# Why do you have to enqueue a stylesheet in wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Why do you have to enqueue the parent theme stylesheet in a WordPress child theme? I've created `style.css` in the child theme and when I add a change to it, it works without the `functions.php` file that enqueues the parent stylesheet, such as changing the background color of an element. I've searched for and answer but can find nothing that tells my why. Everything just says that you have to.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: if you dont enqueue the parent stylesheet or import it (look for "import" at the top of your child theme) , none of the css properties in it will be loaded (view page source to look for stylesheets that  get loaded). So if you can do without these, no problem.

Comment: ps i note you have asked a question before and not accepted the answer given or replied, kind of rude!

Comment: Thanks. I don't get on here often, I will go accept answers. Sorry.

Comment: It appears that it loads that parent css file anyway, then applies the css file in the child directory.  Everything works without enqueueing anything. I don't understand lol

Comment: because it is already done for you, see the below answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to loading the styles in WordPress themes there are many ways to skin a cat.

**Parent enqueues child style.css -**
In some themes the parent `style.css` is enqueued with `wp_enqueue_style()` within the parent theme `php` code.

The 2015 default theme is an example of this method. In `functions.php` line 233 there is the line `wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfifteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );`. When the theme is standalone `get_stylesheet_uri()` returns the theme's own `style.css`. When a child theme is present `get_stylesheet_uri()` returns the *child theme* `style.css`.

The above is the likely case for your parent theme.

**Child enqueues parent style.css -**
From the child theme you can load the parent styles by by one of two methods.

1. `enqueue_style()` with parameters pointing to the parent theme. Some php similar to: `wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );`. This is the method you are talking about.
2. `@import` from within the child theme `style.css` file. A typical line of code for this would read: `@import url( '../parent-theme-folder/style.css' );`. This is not ideal as `@import` slows down your page load time.

**Better Method - Don't use root style.css** 
It's not strictly necessary to use `style.css` in the root folder at all. The only thing WordPress strictly needs this file for is to read the theme information in the top comments. This very requirement means that the `style.css` can't be minimised, or at least is a pain to minimise. Minimising is the process of removing all the spaces in a file of code to reduce the file size. This reduces page load speed.

So now a lot of modern themes are enqueuing their main style from a different minimised `css` file in a theme subfolder. The main `style.css` simply consists of the informational comment section read by the core php code but not loaded on the front end.

Comment: just to point out a lot of themes use get_stylesheet_uri which will look in the child theme first. other than that good answer.

Comment: @David thanks for catching, I'll edit when back at pc

Comment: Thanks to both of you. So because the theme I'm developing a child for (woocommerce's storefront) probably does the enqueue already, that is why my css file with style changes in my child directory works even though I haven't even created a functions.php file in the child directory (from what I'm understanding from the answer).